# The tricky thief

Tags: probability

I came up with a problem on my walk home, and I have no idea where to start on it:

A thief decides to steal all of his neighbor's mail.  He decides that he should wait an exponential amount of time $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}_\lambda$ between thefts.  The USPS can't afford daily surveillance, so they also wait am amount of time $Y\sim \lfloor\mathrm{Exp}_\gamma\rfloor$ between stakeouts, which they do for a whole 24 hours.  (This is the floor of an exponential rv)

What is the expected time until the thief gets caught?

I do have some thoughts, but no real work:

The thief gets caught on day $\lfloor Z\rfloor = \sum_j Y_j$ if $Z = \sum_i X_i$ for some sequences $Y_j$ and $X_i$.  Z is clearly gamma.

It looks like we can use linearity of expectation to get $E(\lfloor Z\rfloor)$ by summing over the expectations of the $Y$'s.

So, the outline of an approach would be to

- compute the distribution of $Z$.
- compute the expectation of $\lfloor Z \rfloor$ by summing:
  $$ \sum_k k P(k \leq Z < k + 1)$$

Does this make sense, at least in principle?  I have no idea how hard that sum would be to compute, but I'll give it a go if I at least formalized everything correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a stakeout of duration $\tau$, the thief is caught if the number of his hits during that time,$N_t(\tau)$, is more than zero.  For the thief's *Poisson process* rate parameter $\lambda$:

$$\begin{aligned} p = P(N_t(\tau) > 0) & = 1-e^{-\lambda\tau}\\ q=P(N_t(\tau) = 0) &= e^{-\lambda\tau}\end{aligned}$$

Use the probability of this happening to determine the expected *number of* stakeouts until this happens.  This is a negative binomial distribution: $N_s \sim\mathcal{NB}(1;p)$

$$\large E(N_s) = \frac{p}{1-p}= e^{\lambda\tau}-1$$

Then find the expected time until this number of stakeouts happen.